# Automatic "zoom" out on low screen resolutions

Tags: html, css, media-queries, resolution, screen-resolution

I have [this](http://goo.gl/F37hG) site. It fits prefectly in resolutions like 1366/1360x768, 1280x1024. But with res equals or lower than 1280x768 it doesn't fit horizontally and of course a scroll bar appears. Is there a way to automatically "zoom out" or some workaround without having to use media queries to reduce image sizes and div widths?

EDIT: I changed CSS a bit to be able to view the website fine till a res of 1024x768. Anyway the question is still valid (not the example link though).

Comment: Why won't you use media queries? You can always use javascript..

Comment: @user1141356 I don't want to have to mantain different stylesheets.. maybe I update the main stylesheet and the edits break something. then I have to check the media queries and it's more work for me.

Comment: well then, i would suggest to you something like this -> http://masonry.desandro.com

Comment: Uhm.. doesn't seem a quick fix. I should rewrite all the theme to use that. anyway another point for not using media queries is that they're not compatible for IE 6-8 (for example), at least without using Respond or something similar.

Comment: I think you are looking for **Responsive Web Design**.

Search both stackoverflow and Google for it and you'll find tutorials and guides on how to make your website adaptable to all kinds of screens, from mobile to giant monitors! ;)